# What would be the most versatile pan for a college/student someone short on time?

Tags: seasoning-pans

I am a complete noob when it comes to cooking, and when one looks at cooking, there seems to a bombardment of various different materials and types and price ranges. I  simply want a reliable pan type, which can last, say, 2-3 years with everyday use, easy to use and season.

Could someone advice me on the same?

Comment: This is too broad. There's no one pan that will do everything, that's why there's so many options. What type of cooking do you want to do?

Comment: Breakfast like eggs, bacon, and maybe things like pasta, browning meat and chicken breats? Just normal low effort dishes @GdD

Comment: @ReineAbstraktion There is no cooking vessel which will be convenient for both pasta and bacon. Different pots/pans are different shapes *for a reason*, and there's simply no "average" one which will be sufficient for "normal dishes".

Comment: The reason why there are so many different pan shapes and materials is that all of them work well for somebody. If you really only want a usable pan, nothing special, just buy any pan you come across.

Comment: @Stephie - done - https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3828/what-defines-opinion-based

Answer (score 3):

This is as broad as all heck & as people have pointed out in comments, getting a pan that will do bacon & eggs & also pasta is pushing it a bit.

There is a type, however, that will *just about* get away with this. Known in the UK as a '**chef's pan**' [yup, really*] it's a wide, semi shallow, flat base but rounded corner pan, with a tight-fitting lid.
It's a bit like a wok, a bit like a frying pan, a bit like a saucepan… but not quite any of them…

[image]
This is mine, 26cm [10.2"] anodised aluminium, laminated base, non-stick. No, it wasn't cheap, but I've had it a decade [which was the guarantee period] & it still looks like new.

Don't put it in a dishwasher. Don't use metal utensils. Don't scrub it with a Brillo scourer. It will last.

*The trouble with it being called a 'chef's pan' is … *all* pans could be described that way, so it tends to lead to some pretty broad google searches:\

Comment: How do you clean this?

Comment: Just run it under a hot tap usually. A bit of dish soap & ten minutes to stand if it was properly claggy. It's non-stick, it really needs nothing more than a rinse.

Comment: You missed the ‘short on time’ aspect of the question.  For that, you need a wok.

Comment: @Joe - I didn't miss it at all. I even said 'it's a bit like a wok'… & can be used as one.

Comment: Maybe, but the idea of a non-stick wok worries me

Comment: @Joe - I also have a [non-stick wok](https://www.cookserveenjoy.com/products/masterclass-carbon-steel-355cm-wok). Restaurant quality. For domestic use it will outlive me.